# Reading ISO 8601 in CSV using Pandas

Tags: pandas

This CSV has dates in ISO 8601 time.

```
0   2014-01-01T00:00:00.000     
1   2014-01-01T00:46:43.000 
2   2014-01-01T01:33:26.001
```

I want to select the rows up until January 2. I'm not sure how to do this. I thought including

```
parse_dates=True
```

would allow me to refer to the date/time values directly like this:

```
sat0 = sat0[sat0['epoch']<2014-01-02T00:00:00.000]
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime()` in converting the target date string column by its appropriate format. In this case, you can use `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'` as the date [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Here's the implementation in your case:

```
import pandas as pd

sat0 = pd.DataFrame({
    'epoch': [
        '2014-01-01T00:00:00.000',
        '2014-01-01T00:46:43.000',
        '2014-03-01T01:33:26.001',
    ]})

date_fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
sat0['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(sat0['epoch'], format=date_fmt)

sat0 = sat0[sat0['epoch'] < '2014-01-02T00:00:00.000']
```

Which outputs

```
                epoch
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00
1 2014-01-01 00:46:43
```